# How to create lists of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to create functions that return a list of ggplot and am having various problems.  Fundamentally however, I do not understand why this is `TRUE`

```
"data.frame" == class(c(qplot(1:10,rnorm(10)))[[1]])
```

when this is `[TRUE,TRUE]`

```
c('gg','ggplot') == class(qplot(1:10,rnorm(10)))
```

I havent seen any questions similar to this. I see various questions that are solved by things like

```
lapply(someList, function(x) {
  #make ggplot, then use print(...) or whatever
  })
```

So I am guessing there is something about passing ggplot objects out of functions or between environments or something.  Thanks for any clues about the ggplot or R that I am missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
p = c(qplot(1:10,rnorm(10)))
p2 = qplot(1:10,rnorm(10))
```

`p[[1]]` (same as `p[['data']])`) is supposed to be a `dataframe`. It usually holds the data for the plot.

`p` is a `list` because you used the `c` function.

`p2` is a `ggplot` because that's what `qplot` returns.

Take a look at the attributes of each object.

```
attributes(p)
# $names
# [1] "data"        "layers"      "scales"      "mapping"     "theme"       "coordinates"
# [7] "facet"       "plot_env"    "labels"  

attributes(p2)
# $names
# [1] "data"        "layers"      "scales"      "mapping"     "theme"       "coordinates"
# [7] "facet"       "plot_env"    "labels"     
# 
# $class
# [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

To store many `ggplot` objects, use `list`.

```
ggplot.objects = list(p2,p2,p2)
```

The `c` help file
shows that `ggplot` is not a possible output. 
It also states that

> `c` is sometimes used for its side effect of removing attributes
>   except names, for example to turn an array into a vector

If you wanted
`c` to return `ggplot` objects, then you could try defining your own `c.ggplot`
function. You'll have to read a good deal about S3 and S4 functions to understand what's
going on.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin for the fast response. It isnt evident why the function `c` described as "..Combine.." would do that but I guess it doesnt matter since List(p2,p2) works.

Answer (score 4):

If you have several ggplot objects in the global environment, you can make a list of them with :

```
ggplot_list <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "ggplot"), mget(ls()))
```